# Port forwarding D-Link DIR-615 (entire network)

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

My wife and I recently purchased a second computer and have started MMO gaming together (namely, World of Warcraft).

For a few weeks now, our DIR-615 seems to be bottle-necking. I'm inclined to believe it may be because of having necessary ports forwarded to one PC, instead of the entire network. Problem is, I'm not quite sure how to do this. When using the standard port forwarding page, you can only specify one IP address and you are not permitted to use the same ports for a different IP address when creating new rules.

Virtual Server is not the answer, of course. I've considered Application Rules, but as I don't have a firewall enabled for the D-Link, I'd imagine that subsection won't work either.

Looking for any input from an experienced user. Thanks!

Comment: You can't forward the same ports to multiple machines from a single public IP, even with a virtual server.  What guide are you following to forward ports, this shouldn't be necessary for WoW?

Comment: Currently using Blizzard's guide: https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/firewall-proxy-router-and-port-configuration

Comment: that page lists the ports that Wow uses, none of them need for be port forwarded.  Some sites block outgoing connections, and these guides are to help you configure firewalls to allow those outgoing connections to get through.

Comment: The general consensus for the community has always seemed to lean toward forwarding ports as a necessity. Perhaps not always for the client, but certainly for the Battle.Net agent / downloader. I've disabled port forwarding, QoS, and enabled UPnP and will give it a go tonight. Not quite sure what causes the bottleneck, as it evens itself out after a few minutes of 5000ms+ latency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and create a rule for every PC that will be running WOW.

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DIR-655/World_of_Warcraft.htm

Comment: If I shouldn't be forwarding ports, then why did you link to a page that tells me to do so? That's a bit confusing!

Comment: ah, i see. you should be able to create multiple rules that will allow the WOW traffic on through the router and to your PC's. Each PC will need its own rule. Have you tried that yet.

Comment: your right... i guess it technically is port forwarding... editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't even think of using a DIR-615 with stock firmware. It's a terribly written piece of ****. Although it is easily one of the cheapest and most adaptable routers made as long as you install DD-WRT or OPENWRT.

You will need the revision number as written on the sticker on the bottom (D1, D2, E3 etc) but once you have that, you will be fine.

Let me know via comments what version you have and I will tell you what you have to do. This router has a 'safety net' feature which means if anything goes wrong, you hold down the reset button whilst powering on, place ethernet between your computer and the router, set your IP to 192.168.0.2/24 and then browse to 192.168.0.1 and you access a hidden webpage where you can upload the firmware of your choice. It really is that simple.